# Dynamic array allocation returns only last element in all indices C

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays, pass-by-value

Okay so I am trying to input data from text file into dynamic arrays of strings. Each data tuple has 6 attributes. Hence 6 arrays. The problem is that when I populate all the arrays, It prints right values in loop.
But when I try to access any of the array's element outside the loop, it gives the last word of text file as output. I have tried all the solutions available and none of them seems to work.

The code is:

```
int  n(FILE **fp, int size,  char **presenters, char **birth_numbers, char **room_codes, 
        char **authors, char **post_titles, char **presentation_types, char **presentation_times, 
        char **dates){
    // Buffer to get input from the file.
    char buffer[200];
    // To check if the file is open or not
    if (*fp == NULL){
        printf("File not Open");
    }
    else{
        char *file = "konferencny_zoznam.txt";
        fseek(*fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        if (size >= 1){
            int length_of_arrays = sizeof presenters / sizeof *presenters;
            if (length_of_arrays > 1){
                printf("in null if");
                free(presenters);
                free(birth_numbers);
                free(room_codes);
                free(authors);
                free(post_titles);
                free(presentation_times);
                free(presentation_types);
                free(dates);
            }

            presenters = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            birth_numbers = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            room_codes = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            authors = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            post_titles = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            presentation_times = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            presentation_types = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));
            dates = malloc((size+1)* sizeof(char*));

            const unsigned MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH = 256;
            char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            int i = 0, len = 0;
        

            while(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp)){
                // len = strlen(buffer)+1;
                presenters[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                birth_numbers[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                room_codes[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                authors[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                post_titles[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                presentation_times[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                presentation_types[i] = buffer;
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);
                dates[i] = buffer;
                printf("buffer : %s", dates[i]);
                fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp);

                i++;
            }
       
            for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
                
                printf("presenter[0]: %s", dates[i]);
                // Outputs 20200406 for each iteration which is the last word of file.

            }
        }
        else {
            printf("File not read already. Consider running command v before.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This declaration int length_of_arrays = sizeof presenters / sizeof *presenters; does not make a sense. It is equivalent to int length_of_arrays = sizeof( char ** ) / sizeof( char * ) ;

Comment: Whenever you assign an element, you are assigning a copy of a pointer to the function's `buffer` array.  As a result, all elements of all arrays point to the same storage, and the contents are whatever was last stored there.  What's more, the lifetime of that object ends when the execution of the `if (size >= 1)` block terminates, leaving those pointers all dangling.  You need to make dynamically-allocated *copies* of `buffer`, and assign pointers to those.

Comment: tip : do an array of structs instead to make it more readable.

Comment: @AndersK The rule is not to use struct in any way.

Comment: You didn't mention your assignment parameters

Comment: Apologies for that.. Actually that wasn't the main problem so I thought I can skip it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do

```
array[i] = buffer;
```

because the buffer is a char array and stores the address of the char array. When you assign its value to a new variable, you are basically copying its address to a new variable. That's why each index of your array is pointing towards the same array that holds the latest value from the file.

You need to perform a deep copy by copying the contents of buffer variable either by strcpy or something else.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the expression used as an initializer in this declaration

```
int length_of_arrays = sizeof presenters / sizeof *presenters;
```

does not make a sense because it is equivalent to

```
int length_of_arrays = sizeof( char ** ) / sizeof( char * );
```

In this while loop

```
        while(fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH, *fp)){
            // len = strlen(buffer)+1;
            presenters[i] = buffer;
            //..
```

all elements `dates[i]` point to the same array

```
dates[i] = buffer;
```

So this loop

```
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
            
            printf("presenter[0]: %s", dates[i]);
            // Outputs 20200406 for each iteration which is the last word of file.

        }
```

outputs what the last was stored in the array buffer.

It seems you need to allocate arrays that will be pointed to by the elements dates[i] and copy there strings from buffer.

Also the function is very complicated. You should combine all parameters starting from the third parameter in a structure.

Take into account that as all the pointers are passed by value then the reallocation of memory within the function will not be reflected in the pointers used as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. There were 2 issues. 1: mentioned by Ehmad i.e We need to use strcpy() while using pointers and the other was that at every step of loop, each index of array needed to have memory allocated separately.